# Regex replacement of a specific string using sed

Tags: regex, macos, unix, sed

I have been facing issues with using regex with sed.
I have a string like :

```
Call stack: [thread 0xac0aaa28]: | start | main main.m:37 | UIApplicationMain | GSEventRun | GSEventRunModal | CFRunLoopRunInMode | CFRunLoopRunSpecific | __CFRunLoopRun | __CFRunLoopDoSource1 | __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ | mshMIGPerform | _XCopyAttributeValue | _AXXMIGCopyAttributeValue | _copyAttributeValueCallback | -[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) accessibilityAttributeValue:] | -[UITableViewCellAccessibilityElement _accessibilityIsTableCell] | -[UITableViewCellAccessibilityElement tableViewCell] | -[UITableViewAccessibility(Accessibility) accessibilityCellForRowAtIndexPath:] | -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForRowAtIndexPath:] | -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] | -[MailViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] | +[NICellFactory tableViewModel:cellForTableView:atIndexPath:withObject:] NICellFactory.m:89 | +[NICellFactory cellWithClass:tableView:object:] NICellFactory.m:67 | -[SwipableTableViewCell shouldUpdateCellWithObject:] | -[SwipableTableViewCell updateCellWithObject:] | -[ThreadCellFrontView updateCellWithObject:] | -[ThreadSummaryView updateWithNugget:] | -[JavaUtilLinkedList init] LinkedList.m:49 | -[JavaUtilLinkedList initJavaUtilLinkedList] LinkedList.m:40 | +[NSObject alloc] | +[NSObject allocWithZone:] | _objc_rootAllocWithZone | class_createInstance | calloc | malloc_zone_calloc
```

which has instances like main.m:37 |, LinkedList.m:95 |, NICellFactory.mm:89 | etc
i.e in text mate I can match these occurences with using the regex

```
[a-zA-z]+[.][m]+[:]+[0-9]+[ |]+
```

Now when I try to do the same thing in sed using

```
sed 's/\[a-zA-z]+[.][m]+[:]+[0-9][ |]+/ /g'
```

Sed does not seem to replace these instances.
I have tried using backlashes too
i.e

```
sed 's/\[a-zA-z\]+\[\.\]\[m\]+\[:\]+\[0-9\]+\[ |\]+/ /g'
```

Still sed does not replace such occurences.

Can someone help me understand what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslashes you added for no good reason are the problem. Also your `sed` dialect may not support `+` repetition out of the box - try with `*` instead, or look for a `-r` or `-E` option in your `sed` manual page.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
sed -i.bck  "s/[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*\.mm*::*[0-9][0-9]*\s|/ /g"  prova_sed.txt
```

It creates a backup file just in case.

May `sed` doesn't seem to support the +, \w and \d syntax so I've used `[a-ZA-Z][a-zA-Z]*` instead of `[a-zA-Z]+`, `mm*` instead of `m+` and so on.

Also note that you don't need to put single characters inside brackets so `[\.][m]+[:]+` can be replaced with `\.mm*::*`

If your sed version supports the -r option the whole thing could be simplified to

```
sed -i.bck  "s/[a-zA-Z]+\.m+:+[0-9]+\s|/ /g"  prova_sed.txt
```